# Reading Excel File With Pandas and Retaining Original Row Number

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I have the following code that reads an Excel file into a Pandas structure:

```
try:
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=filecontent)
    file = pd.read_excel(book)
    ...
rows = file.values
```

Later, I do something like this

```
        rows = sorted(
            rows,
            key=lambda vs: '' if not nan_to_none(vs[columns_map['order_name']]) else vs[columns_map['order_name']]
        )
```

When processing `rows`, I would like to throw errors that indicate line numbers where they occurred in the original Excel file. My thinking was that I should retain those line numbers somehow and later send them with errors. How can I do that or how can I achieve my goal if there is another way to do it?

Comment: Why not work with a `DataFrame` here, where the index can easily serve this purpose?

Comment: @BigBen Sounds good. How? Wouldn't the sorting change the index and hence lose the original values?

Comment: No, sorting does not change the index.

Comment: @BigBen How would I address the index within `rows`? When inspecting it in debugger, it doesn't seem to have any index field.

Comment: You'd work with `file`, not `rows`.

Comment: @BigBen That would involve a lot of refactoring downstream in my case or so it seems. Hence, I was looking for the most painless solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
```

Then

```
# Assuming you have the rest of your code as shown in the question
try:
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=filecontent)
    file = pd.read_excel(book)
    ...
    rows = file.values
    # Add an additional column 'line_number' to store the original line numbers
    file['line_number'] = range(1, len(file) + 1)
except Exception as e:
    # Handle exceptions and keep track of line numbers       
    raise CustomError("Error at line {}".format(len(file) + 1)) from e
```

Later, when processing rows, you can use the **line_number** column to get the **original** line number

```
rows = sorted(
    rows,
    key=lambda vs: '' if not nan_to_none(vs[columns_map['order_name']]) else vs[columns_map['order_name']]
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Where will line number for each entry (row) be populated in your example?

Comment: I'm not sure if i understood you, but basically we are reading excel as a pandas dataframe and creating an additional column **line_number**

Comment: Right, but what values will that column contain and how will they get into that column?

Comment: Will contain the row number by  using this line: file['line_number'] = range(1, len(file) + 1) is simply generating 1 to file rows total lines.